Linearity of isometric mappings of a complex Hilbert space
Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space and $f:H\to H$ a map such that $||f(x)-f(y)||=||x-y||$
and $f(0)=0$. We want to show that $f$ is linear or conjugate linear.
From $f(0)=$ we get $||f(x)||=||x||$ and expanding the equality $||f(x)-f(y)||^2=||x-y||^2$
then yields
$$
Re(f(x),f(y)) = Re(x,y),\quad,\forall x,y\in H,
$$
where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes the inner product on $H$ and $Re\lambda$ is the real part
of the scalar $\lambda$.
Now let $\lambda\in R$ be a real scalar and $x,y\in H$.
Using $||u-v||^2=||u||^2+||v||^2-2Re(u,v)$, we can write
\begin{align*}
&||f(\lambda x+y)-[\lambda f(x)+f(y)]||^2=
\\&\phantom{----}
||[f(\lambda x+y)-f(y)]-\lambda f(x)||^2=
\\&\phantom{----}
||f(\lambda x+y)-f(y)||^2+|\lambda|^2||f(x)||^2 - 2Re\big(f(\lambda x+y)-f(y),\lambda f(x)\big)=
\\&\phantom{----}
2|\lambda|^2||x||^2 - 2Re\big[\big(f(\lambda x+y),\lambda f(x)\big)-\big(f(y),\lambda f(x)\big)\big]=
\\&\phantom{----}
2|\lambda|^2||x||^2 - 2\lambda Re\big[\big(f(\lambda x+y),f(x)\big)-\big(f(y),f(x)\big)\big]=
\\&\phantom{----}
2|\lambda|^2||x||^2 - 2\lambda Re\big[\big(\lambda x+y,x\big)-\big(y,x\big)\big]=
\\&\phantom{----}
2|\lambda|^2||x||^2 - 2\lambda^2Re(x,x) = 0.
\end{align*}
which shows that $f$ is real linear. It now remains to show only that
$$
f(i x)=if(x), \forall x\in H,\text{ or }f(i x)=-if(x), \forall x\in H.
$$
But I cannot come up with a proof. I could not find anything on the internet either.

It’s just not true: $f: \mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}^2$ defined by $f(a, b) = (\bar{a}, b)$ satisfies $f(0) = 0$ and is isometric, but it is neither linear nor conjugate linear.

OK, thanks, that explains my problems.
